# How can we find a details view placed outside gridview inside gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

What I particularly want is to find details view inside gridview which is placed outside the gridview is it possible ? I want that to happen on GridView RowCommand. Every time I try to find it the control remains null.

This is what I am doing :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("edit"))
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string r = GridView1.DataKeys[id - 1].Value.ToString();

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[id];

        DetailsView  dv = (DetailsView)ridView1.Rows[id].FindControl("DetailsView1");  // getting it as null
        dv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      // Object refrence not set to instance of object: Error
        dv.DataBind();
        dv.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should show us the relevant part of your aspx since this sounds like a riddle: _"find details view inside gridview which is placed outside the gridview"_

Comment: Show your GridView Markup too

Comment: I am confused.  DetailsView  dv = (DetailsView)ridView1.Rows[id].FindControl("DetailsView1"); will get a DetailsView that is a Child control of the GridView1DataView.
But if your DetailsView is not in the gridview, you will never find it like this. Like above said, can you post your relevent aspx code.